# Can't find the database's package

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am creating an Android application and it have a lot of packages.
I need to do a database backup, and I don't know which package it is.

```
File dbFile =new File(Environment.getDataDirectory() +"/data/Your.Package/databases/databaseName.db");
```

Is "Your.Package" the package where my SQLite classes is?

I am gettin :

```
[Configuracoes.java:235:doInBackground()] /data/data/org.Database/databases/banco.db (No such file or directory)
```

When I try the package where I created the database.

Where is the correct one?

I am sorry if it is a stupid question.

Comment: What's your main Activity canonical name?

Comment: **Canonical** name, e.g. `your.package.yourClassName`. As returned by `MiniNegocioActivity.class.getCanonicalName()`.

Comment: org.MiniNegocio.MiniNegocioActivity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Location of your database is

/data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE/databases/ab.db

You can find it on Android manifest file.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:versionCode="0.0"
  package="YOUR_PACKAGE" android:versionName="1.0">
```

Comment: minhaz I already tried this name... doesn't work.
my database name is "banco.db".
I already tried '/data/data/org.MiniNegocio/databases/banco.db'

and '/data/data/org.MiniNegocio/databases/banco'

Comment: Then check your SQLiteOpenHelper code if you used some other location, if not make sure that your database is really created.